# xk6-sql extension: db connection cannot be passed from setup() stage

Tags: k6

I had a test case where there were 2 scenarios to insert data to MySQL tables via xk6-sql extension. Here is the structure of my code.

main.js

```
import sql from "k6/x/sql";
export { runtest1 } from "./runtest1.js";
export { runtest2 } from "./runtest2.js";

const testConfig = JSON.parse(open("./conf.json"));
export const options = Object.assign(
  {
    insecureSkipTLSVerify: false,
  },
  testConfig
);

export function setup() {
  const db = sql.open("mysql", "root:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/testing");
  console.log(db);
  return db;
}

export default function () {
  console.log("running test cases...");
}

export function teardown(data) {
  data.db.close();
}
```

runTest1.js

```
export function runtest1(data) {
  data.db.exec(
    `INSERT INTO cats1 (name, breed, age) VALUES ('test1-2', 'Doodle', 1)`
  );
}
```

runTest2.js

```
export function runtest2(data) {
  data.db.exec(
    `INSERT INTO cats1 (name, breed, age) VALUES ('test2-2', 'Doodle', 2)`
  );
}
```

config.json

```
{
  "scenarios": {
    "scenario1": {
      "executor": "shared-iterations",
      "vus": 1,
      "iterations": 1,
      "exec": "runtest1"
    },
    "scenario2": {
      "executor": "shared-iterations",
      "vus": 1,
      "iterations": 1,
      "exec": "runtest2"
    }
  }
}
```

I received the **TypeError: Cannot read property ‘exec’ of undefined or null** from the 2 scenarios. Can anyone explain why the db connection was not able to passed from setup()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup()` can only return JSON data, not arbitrary JavaScript objects.

You must open the connection in the *init context* (outside of any function), as is shown in the [example in the README](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-sql#example):

> ```
> import sql from 'k6/x/sql';
>
> const db = sql.open("sqlite3", "./test.db");
>
> export function setup() {
>   db.exec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyvalues (
>            id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
>            key varchar NOT NULL,
>            value varchar);`);
> }
>
> export function teardown() {
>   db.close();
> }
> ```

So in your case:

```
import sql from "k6/x/sql";
export { runtest1 } from "./runtest1.js";
export { runtest2 } from "./runtest2.js";

const testConfig = JSON.parse(open("./conf.json"));
export const options = Object.assign(
  {
    insecureSkipTLSVerify: false,
  },
  testConfig
);

const db = sql.open("mysql", "root:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/testing");

export function teardown(data) {
  data.db.close();
}

export default function () {
  console.log("running test cases...");
}
```